# Presenting extended UIViewController Class IOS (Obj-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have an iPhone email like application that uses an extended UIViewController class called messageDetail for the class. I use a separate storyboard for the UI for this view (which has the messageDetail class as its base), but have a storyboard reference from the main storyboard, along with a segue.

In my code, I instantiate the messageDetail class, modify properties, but when I try to present it I either get an all black view, or an unhandled exception error in main. My code is:

```
messageDetail *md = [[messageDetail alloc] init];
md.toField.text = @"email@yahoo.com";
md.ccField.text = @"otheremail@yahoo.com";
md.body.text = @"This is the body of the email I am sending";
md.subject.text = @"Important update...";

UIViewController *top = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
[top presentViewController:md animated:YES completion: nil];
```

I know the class is working properly, it's just something I am doing wrong with trying to get the view presented. The UI view shows for messageDetail, but none of the modified properties are changed in the view. I know this is basic stuff for most of you, but can someone please offer some help?

Comment: If you created your view controller in the storyboard you have to instantiate using the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method on `UIStoryboard`

Comment: Thanks. I tried: UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"messageDetail"                                                 bundle:nil]; [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"messageDetail"]; But I can't figure out how to pass the modified md instance to this. Can you help?